# check dynamic array against static array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some javascript/jquery for this. I have two arrays, one static array that is hard coded and another dynamic array that is user driven. For example the values in each array represent a div. Each div is represented in the static array. I want to be able to show only the divs that are present in the dynamic array. So if the dynamic array changes, it shows the divs present in the dynamic array and hides the divs not present. I also want to be able to run a function connected to each div, ie box1 has a function that needs called if it is displayed.

```
var static_list = new Array("box1","box2","box3");
var dynamic_list = new Array("box1","box3");
```

Comment: To clarify, are the values in the array the ID attributes of these div elements?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that `dynamic_list` is a subset of `static_list`.

```
$.each(static_list, function(index, value) {
  $('#' + value).hide();
});

$.each(dynamic_list, function(index, value) {
  $('#' + value).show();
});
```

`$.each()` iterates through a collection calling the callback function for each element. The first `$.each()` hides all elements with IDs found in the `static_list`. The second `$.each()` shows all elements with IDs found in the `dynamic_list`. Running both in that order hides all div elements in `static_list` except for those found in the `dynamic_list`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple comparator function:

```
// Return true if value is in array
function isIn(value, array) {
  var i = array.length;
  while (i--) {
    if (array[i] == value {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

then you can see if a value is in an array using:

```
if (isIn(value, array)) {
  // do something with/to value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your result by using [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/), and [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
$.each(static_list, function(index, value){
    var showHide = $.inArray(value, dynamic_list) >= 0;
    $("#" + this).toggle(showHide);
});
```

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/ByD2N/1/).**